# google apps script doGet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having problems with this code.  Google deprecated several pieces that were working. Now when making a new sheet and trying to use the old code, I get errors and can't find the way to make changes with the documentation at google.

```
function doGet(e) {

    //This is not working?

    if (typeof e.parameter.id  == 'undefined'){     
        return no_id(e) // The URL doesn't have an ?id=345 on the end!
    }

    var id = parseInt( e.parameter.id ) // This is the id of the row in the spreadsheet.

    //Script properties is changed and I think it is now: PropertyService.getScriptProperties() // Get the data from the spreadsheet and get the row that matches the id

    var this_spreadsheet_id = ScriptProperties.getProperty('this_spreadsheet_id')
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(this_spreadsheet_id)
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    var range = sheet.getDataRange()
    var last_row = range.getLastRow()
    var last_column = range.getLastColumn()

    for(i = 2; i <= last_row ; i++){

        var this_row = sheet.getRange(i,1 , 1, last_column)
        var values = this_row.getValues()[0]
        var row_id = parseInt( values[0] )

        //row id == id is not working either

        if ( row_id == id){        
            var title = values[5]
            var details = values[8]
            var status_txt = values[7]

            Logger.log( "STATUS: " + status )

            var image_url = values[4]
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea's would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: please use the apps script debugger to step line by line. include values of each variable in in your code above.

Comment: What was working that Google deprecated?

Comment: I figured out the script change for script properties.  The  **if ( row_id == id)** is where the debugger gets tripped up now.  Currently the debugger reads **"ReferenceError: "id" is not defined. (line 23, file "Code")"**  The id is set up in the top var id.  I just have no clue and getting really frustrated.

Comment: I don't understand the parseInt command, frankly I don't understand much.  I'm trying to learn and am working on a project as a volunteer and am getting tripped up.

Answer (score 0):

"ReferenceError: "id" is not defined. (line 23, file "Code")"

You  have a return in an if statement before the id is defined. So if it is not being defined then the if statement is being triggered. Move your  variable definitions to the top.

```
var id = parseInt( e.parameter.id ) // This is the id of the row in the spreadsheet.

//Script properties is changed and I think it is now: PropertyService.getScriptProperties() // Get the data from the spreadsheet and get the row that matches the id

var this_spreadsheet_id = ScriptProperties.getProperty('this_spreadsheet_id')
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(this_spreadsheet_id)
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var range = sheet.getDataRange()
var last_row = range.getLastRow()
var last_column = range.getLastColumn()

if (typeof e.parameter.id  == 'undefined'){     
    return no_id(e) // The URL doesn't have an ?id=345 on the end!
}
```